# ATI gamma correction, fglrx_xgamma not installed

Tags: ati

I want to change gamma settings after installing ATI driver. But I noticed that I have no `fglrx_xgamma` tool. I installed the drivers from the ATI website.

How to correct gamma without the tool, or change it in the other way?